# How to calculate date and change the format of the date

Tags: javascript

How to calculate the date and change the date format.
I can't compare the date code below. I want to know why? I want an example to compare date or calculate day results of different days

- I want to change format before and after that comparing date (formatDate: dd/mm/yyyy)

```js
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var d1 = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
//alert(d1); change format date completed 12/04/2019

var date2 = new Date("04/12/2018");
var curr_date2 = date2.getDate();
var curr_month2 = date2.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year2 = date2.getFullYear();
var d2 = curr_date2 + "/" + curr_month2 + "/" + curr_year2;
//alert(d2); // change format date completed 12/04/2018

if (d1 > d2) {
  console.log("aaa");
} else {
  console.log("bbb");
}
```

Comment: Why can't you compare dates? What are you expecting and what is happening instead right now?

Comment: You could use moment.js to do all these in much simple way

Comment: Your code is working fine.. what u want?

Comment: i want to change format before and after that comparing date

Comment: @TanaphonPrayoonprasop would you care to explain more about your issue because we people are having trouble to understand

Comment: your `d1 > d2` returns `aaa` which is correct. What else you need ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with the first part of your code when you are converting them from JavaScript Date objects to the mentioned date formats.

However, when it comes to comparing the dates, you should use [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on the Date objects.

```
if(d.getTime() > date2.getTime()) {
  console.log("aaa");
}else{
  console.log("bbb");
}
```

What you tried to do on your code is to compare d1 and d2, which is wrong because they are both strings, and will likely give you the wrong solution.

Here is the full code. Basically, you only need to change the last chunk of your code with that if.. else statement.

```js
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var d1 = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
console.log(d1);
//alert(d1); change format date completed 12/04/2019

var date2 = new Date("04/12/2018"); 
var curr_date2 = date2.getDate();
var curr_month2 = date2.getMonth() + 1; 
var curr_year2 = date2.getFullYear();
var d2 = curr_date2 + "/" + curr_month2 + "/" + curr_year2;
console.log(d2);
//alert(d2); // change format date completed 12/04/2018
console.log(d.getTime())
console.log(date2.getTime())

// only change the below
if(d.getTime() > date2.getTime()) {
  console.log("aaa");
} else {
  console.log("bbb");
}
```

Comment: i want to change format before and after that comparing date

Comment: Ok, so after comparing date at `if(d.getTime() > date2.getTime())`, what do you want?